# How to disable foobar2000's "Total time played" feature?

Tags: foobar2000

It can be seen in File > Preferences > Playback window.

For me, it's just a waste of resources. I checked even File > Preferences > Advanced > Playback and found nothing.

Maybe to edit some configuration text file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exact performance issue are you experiencing with this function to conclude that it is a "waste of ressources"?

Comment: Checking the time passed will take some microseconds, no performance issues are possible.

Comment: I have quite an old low-performance computer, so everything counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, counting seconds is far from being resource intensive or wasteful for a computer. Calculating is literally what these machines are built for, it would be a shame if simply counting seconds would lead to a performance impact and would probably make it impossible to count milli or microseconds (as commonly done in code).

Apart from that foobar2000 is closed source.

If there is no option in the preferences to configure a certain aspect of the software, you have to live with the way the developer set it up.

Comment: It's clear now.